# How to copy files from desktop folder to usb via VB.net

Tags: vb.net, windows-7

There are 5 PCs in my shop 3 windows 7 and 2 windows XP. Every PC is operated by different users with their account (Account names are different). A main folder called "papers" (unique) is in every PC's desktop. The folder "papers" contains subfolders and files also. I want to copy that folder(papers) to my USB stick when I clicked the application from the root of the USB.

```
User 1 : C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\papers\
User 2 : C:\Users\Ruwan\Desktop\papers\
User 3 : C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\papers\
User 4 : C:\Users\Roshy\Desktop\papers\
User 5 : C:\Users\Veronica\Desktop\papers\

Here the user's name is change to different users.
```

In the coding, I assigned the value for FileToCopy as a single file (Java_OOPs.docx). I want to chage the FileToCopy value, to copy the entire "papers" folder to the USB.

My question is how to copy the folder (papers) and sub folder to the USB and a common name (Because the user's name is changing) for the desktop folder(access the desktop "papers" folder)

Note : This application may able to run on Windows XP too.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim Gig As Long = 1073741824
    Dim FileToCopy As String = "C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\papers\Java_OOPs.docx"

    Try
        For Each drive As System.IO.DriveInfo In System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives
            If drive.DriveType = IO.DriveType.Removable AndAlso drive.IsReady AndAlso drive.AvailableFreeSpace >= 2 * Gig Then

                Dim DriveLetter As String = drive.Name
                Dim PathToUSBDrive = DriveLetter & IO.Path.GetFileName(FileToCopy)
                IO.File.Copy(FileToCopy, PathToUSBDrive)

            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Have you tried https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz2d9afk.aspx ?

Comment: No, but the link says about copy directory. How it is helpful for me?

Comment: @testteam, because what you are doing is copying from directories?

Comment: I want to copy files and sub folders from desktop papers folder.

Comment: Just in case: you are aware that folder = directory, right?

Comment: Sure the is folder

Comment: This method will copy a directory from source to destination, including subdirectories and contents. Also, I think you should establish the drive letter first and then copy. By looping through GetDrives, you might inadvertently copy a directory to another removable drive.

Comment: `Dim FileToCopy As String = "C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\papers\Java_OOPs.docx"`
means a specific file as the source. But I want to copy all files and sub folders in the folder papers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim Gig As Long = 1073741824L
        Dim FolderToCopy As String = IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "papers")

        Try
            For Each Drive As IO.DriveInfo In IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives
                Select Case True
                    Case Not Drive.DriveType = IO.DriveType.Removable
                    Case Not Drive.IsReady
                    Case Not Drive.AvailableFreeSpace >= 2 * Gig
                    Case Else
                        Debug.Print("Copying {0} to {1}", FolderToCopy, Drive.RootDirectory.FullName)
                        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(FolderToCopy, Drive.RootDirectory.FullName, True)

                        ' Only do the copy once to first appropriate drive
                        Exit For
                End Select
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print(ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Idea for improvement: replace `Drive.RootDirectory.FullName` with `IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(IO.Path.Combine(Drive.RootDirectory.FullName, Environment.UserName)).FullName` which would create a folder in the root of the USB drive of the user's name and copy the files into it, so the same USB could be used for multiple users or machines.

Comment: how can I chage this to copy all contents  (files, folders and sub folders) from the desktop, rather than copy the entire folder "papers".

Comment: Replace `IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "papers")` with `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop` at the top of the code sample.

Comment: what should I do to run this application that may able to work on windows XP ?

Comment: XP is dead, but you can try compiling it to .Net 3.5 or lower.

Comment: I compiled it with .Net 2.0, but it was not wok in XP.

Comment: Suggest you try Google, and search SO for help, and if that doesn't get you an answer, start a new question with your new problem with XP.